# How to create clean URLs for category strings?

Tags: url

This code for linking to a category page:

```
href="/products/?category={{ category.slug }}"
```

Generates this URL:  `www.website.com/products/?category=category-name`

Can someone please tell me how to code links in menus (etc) that will produce URLs without the `?category=` string being included in the URL.  So that the URL would become: `www.website.com/products/category-name`

Many thanks for your help - it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First thing you'll need to do is set up a route that ensures anything for /products/category-name gets routed to the correct template. You can do this from the control panel or via `craft/config/routes.php`

If you do this in your routes.php file you'd need something like this:

```
return array(
    'products/(.*?)' => 'products/index',
);
```

Which is telling Craft that for any url that contains `products/any-characters` it should use the `products/index` template.

Then, on that template, grab the segment that is the category slug

```
{% set catSegment = craft.request.segment(2) %}
```

You'll then need to get the category that has that slug

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(catSegment).first() %}
```

You then have a category model you can work with and can use a craft entries tag with a category criteria using

```
{% set products = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).find() %}
```

Loop through `products` to output your products.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply - it's very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm still getting a 404 error for: www.website.com/products/category-name

Using this mark-up on the menu.

{% for category in craft.categories.group('products').level(1).all() %}
<a class="dropdown-item {{ active(category.slug) }}" href="/products/{{ category.slug }}" title="{{ category.title }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}

Comment: Did you set up a route so that Craft knows which template to use?

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for taking the time to reply - it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I added a new route (via the control panel), specifically for the test category of:
products/(.*?) to load the products/index template

Comment: But unfortunately, I still just get a 404 error, unless the URL includes:

?category=

Is this (another) problem with Craft 3?